# Null useState issue when state is not null in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-functional-component

some trouble with state in TypeScript React.

A Child component passes a ’terminal’ object to the Parent through a passed function named `returnTerminal()`. This terminal object is then stored as a useState `_object`. `useEffect()` says that `_object` is not null eventually, but `callback()` continuously maintains that `_object` is null, and I’m not sure why.

**Parent Component**

```
const Parent: React.FunctionComponent<ParentProps> = () => {
  const [_object, set_object] = useState<Terminal>(null);

  const handleGetTerminal = (terminal: Terminal) => {
    set_object(terminal);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (_object !== null) {
      _object.writeln("_object is not null"); // This prints just fine
    }
  }, [_object]);

  return (
    <Child
      returnTerminal={(term) => handleGetTerminal(term)}
      callback={() => {
        console.log(_object === null); // This returns true - the object is null for some reason???
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

**Child Component**

```
const Child: React.FunctionComponent<ChildProps> = (props) => {
  const { callback, returnTerminal } = props;

  // The ref where the terminal will be stored and returned
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  // The xterm.js terminal object
  const terminal = new Terminal();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // Calls whenever terminal is typed into
    if (callback) terminal.onData(callback);

    // Mount terminal to the DOM
    if (ref.current) terminal.open(ref.current);

    // Pass the terminal to the parent object
    returnTerminal(terminal);
  }, []);

  return <div ref={ref}></div>;
};

export default Child;
```

The `callback()` always returns that `_object` is null, no matter how long I wait.

Comment: The comment: `console.log(_object === null); // This returns false - the object is null for some reason???` seems incorrect. It is `false` because it does have a value, it ISN'T equal to `null`?

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` hook callback runs only once and closes over the `callback` and `terminal` in scope. `const terminal = new Terminal();` also creates a new terminal each render cycle, is this intentional?

Comment: Can you try replacing `_object === null` with `typeof _object === "object" && _object !== null"`, because `null` is actually considered of type `Object` in JS

Comment: This pattern is not common. It's weird that you have a parent hold a value of a child. It would be prettier to have the parent holding the terminal object and passing it to the child instead of the parent being assigned a variable from the child

Comment: @Yooooomi it could be a common parent for different components that use that value, there's nothing weird about that.

Comment: Then in my opinion you should create the terminal in the parent and share to all the children you want from the parent directly. If the resource is generated by the child and is meant to be that way, OP should take a look at stores, because the value is meant to be accessible from anywhere in the website

Comment: @Yooooomi my goal was for Child to be a library module - I wanted to create a common Xterm.js package for React. The parent should be able to directly access the terminal of any library child it creates, including if there are multiple ‘children’.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being the use of useImperativeHandle and forwardRef. Here’s the completed code.

**Parent**

```
import Child from "./child";

interface ParentProps {
  name?: string;
}

const Parent: React.FunctionComponent<ParentProps> = () => {
  type ChildHandle = ElementRef<typeof Child>;
  const childRef = useRef<Child>(null);

  let _object: Terminal;  // same Terminal type that Child uses

  useEffect(() => {
    if (childRef.current) {
      _object = childRef.current.get(); // imperitive handle function
      _object.writeln(“_object loaded”);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Child
      ref={childRef}
      callback={() => {
        terminal.writeln("_object is not null”);  // THIS finally works
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

**Child**

```
interface ChildProps {
  callback?(data: string): void;
}

type ChildHandle = {
  get: () => Terminal;
};

const Child: ForwardRefRenderFunction<ChildHandle, ChildProps> = (
  props,
  forRef
) => {
  const { callback } = props;

  const terminal = new Terminal();

  // The ref where the terminal will be stored and returned
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useImperativeHandle(forRef, () => ({
    get() {
      return terminal;
    },
  }));

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // Calls whenever terminal is typed into
    if (callback) terminal.onData(callback);

    // Mount terminal to the DOM
    if (ref.current) terminal.open(ref.current);
  }, []);

  return <div ref={ref}></div>;
};

export default forwardRef(Child);
```